# How to get XMLTAGs/Attribute from the clob column

Tags: xml, plsql, clob

*for below clob/xml I want to get all the xmlatgs like FirstName LAST NAME Not the values only name of the tags.* in my Table I have clob column which stores clob data and I want to extract all possible xmltags.
"

```
 "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<emailRequest project="KLM" region="ALL" letterType="ABC" customerType="ABC" language="en" xmlns="http://test.xml.com/xmlService">
    <trackingId>1234</trackingId>
    <ban>678</ban>
    <header>
        <to>noemail@noemail.com</to>
        <from>Update</from>
        <subject>XL&amp;XL Processed for 1234</subject>
        <fromAlias>Update</fromAlias>
    </header>
    <body>
        <templateData>
            <dataField name="ServiceType">Wireless</dataField>
            <dataField name="AcctLast4">xx</dataField>
            <dataField name="AcctType">yy</dataField>
            <dataField name="PaymentAcctLast4">xx</dataField>
            <dataField name="PayConfirmNumber">ABC</dataField>
            <dataField name="PayDate">06/18/2018</dataField>
            <dataField name="AmountPaid">xx</dataField>
            <dataField name="FAN">N/A</dataField>
            <dataField name="FirstName">xx</dataField>
            <dataField name="LastName">xx</dataField>
            <dataField name="CustomerName">yy</dataField>
            <dataField name="FName">xx</dataField>
            <dataField name="LName">xx</dataField>
            <dataField name="datacenterInfo">BR</dataField>
        </templateData>
    </body>
    <clientData>
        <dataField name="WirelessInd">Y</dataField>
        <dataField name="WirelineInd">N</dataField>
        <dataField name="UverseInd">N</dataField>
        <dataField name="MultiProductInd">N</dataField>
        <dataField name="AutoPayInd">U</dataField>
        <dataField name="BillingOptInd">Unknown</dataField>
        <dataField name="RegistrationStatus">U</dataField>
    </clientData>
</emailRequest>
"
```

Comment: What have you already done? Share the code.

Comment: I tries using getrootelement() but didn't get anything

Comment: Can someone please help?